# Azure .net 5 isolated functions: Using middleware to catch exceptions

Tags: c#, azure, function, middleware

As the title says, I'm trying to handle Exceptions in my Azure functions middleware. It should be possible according to [some](https://www.re-mark-able.net/blogs/2021/05/09/azure-functions-middleware.html) [articles](https://bytelanguage.net/2021/06/09/introduction-to-isolated-azure-functions-net-5/), but I've not managed to make their code work for me. I've also checked [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware) but that didn't handle Exception handling.

My code:

`Program.cs:`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MiddleWareTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionLoggingMiddleware>();
                    }
                )
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

`ExceptionLoggingMiddleware.cs:`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MiddleWareTest
{
    public class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
    {
        public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = context.GetLogger(context.FunctionDefinition.Name);
                logger.LogError("Unexpected Error in {0}: {1}", context.FunctionDefinition.Name, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Function1.cs`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace MiddleWareTest
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [Function("Function1")]
        public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            throw new Exception("yo");
        }
    }
}
```

To my understanding this code should suffice to handle Exceptions, but whenever I execute `Function1`, the exception does not get handled by my Middleware, it's uncaught.

My question:

**What am I missing/doing wrong in order to implement Exception handling in my Azure Functions Middleware?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I pulled your github project and i couldn't even get it to run. I created a brand new Http Trigger Azure Function using .NET 5 and copy and pasted your code and it worked perfectly. I am assuming there is something wrong with your solution. Please note that if you are in a Debugger, you should step-over the exception breaks so they can propagate to your middleware.

Comment: also, try updating `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` to version "1.5.2". I noticed that was out of date (currently at 1.1.0)

Comment: Updating my `Functions.Worker` package worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204153/andy) for your suggestions, We believe the issue has been fixed as a result of the discussions in the comments, thus we are turning the above comments to an Answer for this thread to assist other community members.

As you may have seen, the issue is that you are using an outdated version of [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker/) updating to the lastest version from your Nuget package manager fixed your issue.